# Sqlite_READONLY error with Electron build in MAC

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I have created a build using electron and npm. The application is using sqlite as a database. The application is ruuning great before creating the build(npm run build). But after creating the build the database become redonly. I have checked the permission by command "ls -asl" but it is showing read/write both the permission to the database file. But when I am trying to insert/update any records is throwing the error "Error: SQLITE_READONLY: Attempt to write a readonly database". I don't know why this is happning. Please provide some help here.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the database file inside the application installation directory, put it in the directory returned by [`app.getPath('userData')`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname) instead.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue; does this solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

The folder the database resides in must have write permissions, as well as the actual database file.

In my case,   I had my sqlite file inside database folder as below

```
 database (Initial permission 665)
     - app.db (Initial permission 665)
```

changed above permission as

```
database (Initial permission 667)
     - app.db (Initial permission 666)
```